# How to fail erb + json rendering when some keys are missing from the json file

Tags: ruby, json, render, erb

We use this ruby script to render our config files from erb template + json config file. It is basically from an example from http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

Recently we accidentally removed something from the json, while we still referenced it in the erb file. The script works, and simply replaces the placeholder with empty string. Is there a way to make it fail?

In the below example

```
$ render.rb conf.json template2.erb out2 ; echo $?
```

will fail with 1, because a full block is missing, however if only some key-value pairs are missing, it doesn't warn or fail:

```
$ render.rb conf.json template1.erb out1 ; echo $?
```

will exit with 0

conf.json:

```
{
  "block1" : {
    "param1": "p1"
  }
}
```

template1.erb:

```
foo=<%= @config['block1']['param1'] %>:<%= @config['block1']['missing_param'] %>
```

template2.erb:

```
foo=<%= @config['block1']['param1'] %>:<%= @config['block1']['missing_param'] %>/<%= @config['missing_block']['anything'] %>
```

render.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# usage: conf_gen.rb config_file.json erb_template output_file

require 'erb'
require 'json'
require 'pathname'

class MyRenderer
  def initialize(config_path)
    @config = JSON.parse(File.read(config_path))
  end
end

if ARGV.size != 3
  puts "Hey, missing arguments.\nUsage: conf_gen.rb <json config file> <erb template> <output file>"
  exit
end

config_path = ARGV.shift
template_filename = ARGV.shift
output_file = ARGV.shift

erb = ERB.new(File.read(template_filename))
erb.filename = template_filename
ConfigRenderer = erb.def_class(MyRenderer, 'render()')
output = File.new(output_file, 'w')
output.puts(ConfigRenderer.new(config_path).render())
output.close

puts "Finished Successfully"
```

Comment: Nice example for me to learn erb a bit more... :)